# standard matrix for a linear transformation for reflection over line (cos, sin)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I need to find the standard matrix for a linear transformation that reflects vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ through the line that goes through the origin in the direction of

$$u=\begin{bmatrix} cos(\alpha) \\ sin(\alpha) \end{bmatrix}$$

I understand what the problem is asking me to do, but I don't know how to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is :

$$\pmatrix{\cos(2 \alpha) & \ \ \sin(2 \alpha)\\
            \sin(2 \alpha) & -\cos(2 \alpha)}.$$

In fact, if $\vec{i},\vec{j}$ is the canonical (orthonormal) basis,

- the first column is the image of $\vec{i}$, thus has a polar angle equal to $2 \alpha$.
- the second column, which is the image is $\vec{j}$, is orthogonal to the first one, with norm one. Thus it is necessarily $\pmatrix{\ \  \sin(2 \alpha)\\
   -\cos(2 \alpha)}.$

[image]